# 16.10 Lightdm failed to start session with i3

Tags: xorg, login, lightdm, session, i3-wm

I have just done a clean server install and run:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm i3
```

The problem is if I reboot and enter my password at the LightDM screen I get the following error: `failed to start session`. If I check the logs I have the following error:

```
DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration ubuntu
DEBUG: Seat: Can't find session 'ubuntu'
```

I did some googling and the only suggestion that got me anywhere was:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
```

Now if I log in using LightDM I get into a screen but none of my `i3` commands work, it does not even take me through the tutorial.

I am guessing I am in some sort of desktop session without a window manager but this is all new territory for me so any clarification would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I finally got this working by taking the following steps.

1) Clean install of ubuntu (minimal or server)

2) `sudo apt-get install lightdm i3`

3) `sudo reboot`

4) Try to login at LightDM screen get the `failed to start session` error

5) Hit `TAB` + `ENTER` to access session picker (my mouse doesn't work until I install drivers but you could use yours) and 're-select' `i3`

6) Try to login again, this time it boots to a black screen

7) Use `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` to get to a `tty` and run `sudo reboot`

8) Login using LightDM and the `i3` config wizard starts and I am able to use my desktop.

I am guessing that step 5-6 are setting the session and creating any necisary files that for some reason do not exist and after that point it is easy to login.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was because at the first time, the default session was ubuntu in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file (if you don't have it you can create it), so when it was looking for it, it did noy find it.

Under the `[SeatDefaults]` you can find `user-session=ubuntu`

This has to be changed to:`user-session=i3`

All in all, it has to be

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=$WHATEVERGREETER
user-session=i3
```

This is just a speculation,  but that is what you have actually done with step5. Maybe this way can also help some people.

Comment: I used `user-session=i3-wm` and had many issues appear, but I changed it to `user-session=i3` and everything's going great!